# Filter List<Object[]> to retain consistent values

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

First, I had a list with several arrays of type Object, e.g.:

```
    Object[] arr1 = new Object[] {"FIM4R1500030", BigInteger.valueOf(5272456l), "A10328E00074531842"};
    Object[] arr2 = new Object[] {"FIM4R1500031", BigInteger.valueOf(886445384123l), "A10328E00074531842"};
    final List<Object[]> arrs = Arrays.asList(arr1, arr2);
```

Then, I wrote a logic that filters them to **retain the consistent values and fills in null for the inconsistent ones**. The result looked something like this:

```
List[
  Object[][null,null,"A10328E00074531842"],
  Object[][null,null,"A10328E00074531842"]
]
```

Now, my problem is that the logic for this turned out rather convoluted and difficult to read and I am not sure whether I can live with it. Also, I don't really want to start writing a fully-blown utility class, since the functionality seems small for this. Here is my code:

```
    final Predicate<Integer> isConsistant = index -> {

        for (Object[] arr : arrs) {
            if (!arr[index].equals(arrs.get(0)[index])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    };

    List<Object[]> filtered = arrs.stream().map(arr -> {

        Object[] returnList = new Object[arrs.get(0).length];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrs.get(0).length; i++) {
            if (isConsistant.test(i)) {
                returnList[i] = arrs.get(0)[i];
            } else {
                returnList[i] = null;
            }
        }

        return returnList;
    })
            .collect(toList());
```

My question is, **how to make this simpler!**

Comment: "how to make this simpler!" http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: For starters, dumping these things into heterogeneous object arrays instead of a proper class is going to make your code a mess no matter what.

Comment: @LouisWasserman agreed - but sadly this is what Hibernate gave me to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want a `List<Object[]>` as the result of your filter? If I understood your problem well, all the `Object[]` inside that list will look the same. So the code could just be:

```
Object[] filtered = IntStream.range(0, arrs.get(0).length)
            .mapToObj(i -> arrs.stream().allMatch(arr -> arr[i] != null && arr[i].equals(arrs.get(0)[i])) ? arrs.get(0)[i] : null)
            .toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this code is not that it's too complex, but that it is unnecessarily slow: for each pair of `(row, column)` of `arrs` you walk the entire array again, trying to determine if all values in the `column` are equal to each other. Essentially, you are running `isConsistant` on the same column `N` times - once for each row, even though the predicate always returns the same value. This may be very significant when the number of rows is high.

The process always ends up with `N` identical rows, so you might as well construct that row once, and make `N` copies of it:

```
Object[] row = new Object[arrs.get(0).length];
for (int i = 0 ; i != arrs.get(0).length ; i++) {
    if (isConsistant.test(i)) {
        row[i] = arrs.get(0)[i];
    }
}
// Now we make N copies of that row:
List<Object[]> filtered = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
for (int i = 0 ; i != arrs.length() ; i++) {
    filtered.add((Object[])row.clone());
}
```

If you are not planning on modifying elements of `filtered`, you may skip the `clone` part, and insert the same object `N` times.

Comment: Its agreed that there is one loop iteration too much in my code - thank you for spotting it! Also, you are right to limit the use of streams since they don't add to readability. Still, I feel it is too much code for what it is doing.

Comment: @FritzDuchardt You can always rewrite the bottom half as a stream `generate`+`limit` to make that part a one-liner. I am sure that the top part can be re-written with streams, too, but I think the readability would suffer compared to the current implantation. It is probably a good idea to merge the code that constructs `row` with `isConsistant`, too, so that the entire code would get even shorter.